# PHPExcel : How to get the cell text and not the formal without calculating the formals during runtime

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel file with 2 worksheets.
1st sheet has almost 5000 rows which are of no use to me.
2nd sheet has 25 rows which are only the required rows, But these rows are obtained from formulas in referring to 1st sheet.

Now the problem is that i am loading only the 2nd sheet using PHPexcel setLoadSheetsOnly() for better performance. Hence system is not able to calculate the formulas which are referring the 1st sheet.

**My Requirement is that i want the read the cell text only (Content Displayed in cell and not the formulas).**

i have used getFormattedValue() and getCalculatedValue() but it doesn't help.

Is there any function or any way by which i can read just the cell text irrespective any formula and without loading the 1st sheet.

will appreciate any inputs/thoughts/recommendations ..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `getCalculatedValue()` method: if that doesn't work, then what does it return?

But if the formula is dependent on data in another sheet, then you need that other sheet loaded else how can the calculation be done.

The other option is the `getOldCalculatedValue()` method; but that isn't guaranteed.

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Get old calculated value (cached)
 * This returns the value last calculated by MS Excel or whichever spreadsheet
 *    program was used to create the original spreadsheet file.
 * Note that this value is not guaranteed to refelect the actual calculated value
 *    because it is possible that auto-calculation was disabled in the original
 *    spreadsheet, and underlying data values used by the formula have changed
 *    since it was last calculated.
 */
```

Comment: Hi Mark Really appreciate your quick response.
I have tried it but it gives error
 "Fatal error: Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object in"  
this is because i am not loading 1st sheet and formulas in 2nd sheet are using cell values in 1st sheet.

Comment: getOldCalculatedValue() seemed to work for me. ill try it out on different cells..

Comment: And it gave below error when i used getCalculatedValue() or getFormattedValue()

    Error Says:
    ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\testapp\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 3241
    Call Stack